# Need help changing/unchanging checkbox label opacity with javascript

Tags: jquery, checkbox, drupal-7

I have a series of 8 checkboxes. Each checkbox has its own label, and the labels have a single background color. I need to add a new class that will change the opacity of any checkboxes that are selected, and then change the opacity back to the original opacity if the user deselects the checkbox(es). I have set up a fiddle where I add a class to the parent element when a checkbox is selected, but it's not exactly what I need. You will see that it adds the class to the top-level div instead of to the individual checkbox div containers.

http://jsfiddle.net/AftyD/1/

```
.red {
background-color:red;
}
.opaque {
opacity: 0.5;
}



<div class="form-checkboxes" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear">
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Boho">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Boho" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Boho]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-1">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-1" class="option"><span class="red">Label 1</span> 
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Classic">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Classic" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Classic]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-2">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-2" class="option"><span class="red">Label 2</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Earthy">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Earthy" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Earthy]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-3">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-3" class="option"><span class="red">Label 3</span> 
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Fashionista">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Fashionista" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Fashionista]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-4">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-4" class="option"><span class="red">Label 4</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Feminine">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Feminine" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Feminine]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-5">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-5" class="option"><span class="red">Label 5</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Nautical">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Nautical" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Nautical]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-6">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-6" class="option"><span class="red">Label 6</span> 
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Sophisticated">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Sophisticated" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Sophisticated]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-7">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-7" class="option"><span class="red">Label 7</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-Sporty">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="Sporty" name="submitted[click_the_looks_you_would_wear][Sporty]" id="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-8">
    <label for="edit-submitted-click-the-looks-you-would-wear-8" class="option"><span class="red">Label 8</span> 
    </label>
</div>
```

```
(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".form-checkboxes").find('input').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) $(this).parent().parent().addClass('opaque')
        else $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('opaque')
    });
});

}(jQuery));
```

Can someone take a look and let me know how I can accomplish this? It's for a Drupal 7 website, so I can't change much in the HTML portion of the fiddle.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing both `.parent().parent()` to `.parent()`? Seems like that is what you want!? http://jsfiddle.net/AftyD/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `parent().parent()` to `next()`.

The element you want to change is a sibling, not the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/AftyD/4/

I didn't notice the comment, using `parent()` will set opacity for the label and the checkbox.  Mine sets the opacity for only the label.  So go with whichever is your goal.